# Issue with IHttpHandler and relative URLs

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, ihttphandler

I've developed a `IHttpHandler` class and I've configured it as `verb="*" path="*"`, so I'm handling all the request with it in an attempt of create my own REST implementation for a test web site that generates the html dynamically.

So, when a request for a .css file arrives, I've to do something like `context.Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(url))` ... same for pictures and so on, I have to response everything myself.

My main issue, is when I put relative URLs in the anchors; for example, I have main page with a link like this `<a href="page1">Go to Page 1</a>` , and in Page 1 I have another link `<a href="page2">Go to Page 2</a>`. Page 1 and 2 are supposed to be at the same level (`http://host/page1` and `http://host/page2`, but when I click in Go to Page 2, I got this url in the handler: `~/page1/~/page2` ... what is a pain, because I have to do an url = url.SubString(url.LastIndexOf('~')) for clean it, although I feel that there is nothing wrong and this behavior is totally normal.

Right now, I can cope with it, but I think that in the future this is gonna bring me some headache. I've tried to set all the links with absolute URLs using the information of `context.Request.Url`, but it's also a pain :D, so I'd like to know if there is a nicer way to do these kind of things.

Don't hesitate in giving me pretty obvious responses because I'm pretty new in web development and probably I'm skipping something basic about URLs, Http and so on.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Is the url variable same as context.Request.Url?

Comment: the url variable uses to contain the context.Request.AbsoluteApplicationPath (i don't remember exactly the name of that property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would take a look at the output HTML delivered to the browser and specifically the links that you are describing.

You say that the link is `<a href="page2">Go to Page 2</a>` but according to your result I would guess it is more like `<a href="~/page2">Go to Page 2</a>`.
You can confirm this by placing a brakepoint in the handler and when it triggers with "~/page1/~/page2" look in the address bar of your browser and it should say something like "http://www.example.com/page1/~/page2"

You should first look at the code generating the link. If it is generated from some kind of function call, make sure you get the web address and not the script address.

In any case these kind of links that switch between first level pages should all start with a "/" indicating that their location is relative to the root of your website rather than relative to the current shown page.